# snapshot.ref is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I'm trying to update a field from a snapshot, but even though the snapshot is not null and printed correctly, I can't seem to use `ref.update()` on it. I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033917/firebase-update-entry-where-value-is). What am I missing here?

My code:

```
 ref.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    var serial_number = String(snapshot.child("serial").val()); // 
    console.log(serial_number);
    snapshot.ref().update({ signed: 'true' });
// ...
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: In Firebase v3, `ref` is a property, not a method.

Comment: Thank you @cartant, such a simple explanation. You can answer the question and I'll accept it if you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the answer you are referencing uses the previous version of Firebase and whilst the API is very close to the current version, there are a few differences.

There is a [guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) that discusses the changes and what needs to be done when upgrading from Firebase version 2 and version 3.

In particular, [many no-argument getters have been changed to read-only properties](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#no-argument_getters_are_now_read-only_properties_numbered):

> **BEFORE**
>
> ```
> // Reference
> var key = ref.key();
> var rootRef = ref.root();
> var parentRef = ref.parent();
>
> // Query
> var queryRef = query.ref();
>
> // DataSnapshot
> ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
>   var dataRef = snapshot.ref();
>   var dataKey = snapshot.key();
> });
> ```
>
> **AFTER**
>
> ```
> // Reference
> var key = ref.key;
> var rootRef = ref.root;
> var parentRef = ref.parent;
>
> // Query
> var queryRef = query.ref;
>
> // DataSnapshot
> ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
>   var dataRef = snapshot.ref;
>   var dataKey = snapshot.key;
> });
> ```

Comment: cartant had already written the solution in a comment, but since your answer is right I have upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @Mr.Phil Yeah, it was my comment. I wrote the comment late last night - my time - but didn't type up a somewhat better formatted answer until this morning.